# How to display/store output of FindMinimum into matrix

Tags: equation-solving

The variables in the following script are a matrix A and a vector b. How can I extract and display them as a complete matrix rather than elements such as a[1,1] or b[1]? I mean similar the format of A0 and B0

```
n = 3;
u = ConstantArray[1, n];
B = Array[b, n];
A = Array[a, {n, n}];
x = A . u;
A0 = {{1.964888535199277, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.157613081677548, 
    0.485375648722841, 0.0}, {0.970592781760616, 3.800280468888800, 
    2.915735525189067}};
B0 = {0.792207329559554, 2.959492426392903, 0.485375638722841};
eqs = {Transpose[B] . u - 1, Transpose[B] . x - 1/2, 
   Transpose[B] . x^2 - 1/3, Transpose[B] . A . x - 1/6};
LT = {A[[1, 2]] == 0, A[[1, 3]] == 0, A[[2, 3]] == 0};
costFunc = Total[eqs^2];
vars = Join[Transpose@{Flatten[A], Flatten[A0]}, Transpose@{B, B0}];
Results = FindMinimum[{costFunc, LT}, vars]



A = Results[[2]][[1 ;; n^2]] // TableForm 
B =  Results[[2]][[n^2 + 1 ;;]] // TableForm
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that I have changed the following expressions slightly to get access to variables.

```
(A = Results[[2]][[1 ;; n^2]]) // TableForm
(B = Results[[2]][[n^2 + 1 ;;]]) // TableForm
```

Make matrices from `A` and `B`:

```
resA = Normal@SparseArray[(A /. a[y_, z_] :> {y, z})]
resB = Normal@SparseArray[(B /. b[y_] :> y)]

(res = Transpose@Join[Transpose[resA], {resB}]) // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.89137 & 0 & 0 & -0.468808 \\
 0.210714 & 0.665948 & 0 & 1.45495 \\
 1.0766 & 3.90015 & 3.04772 & 0.0138558 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: I would define the matrix elements as indexed variables not as functions.

Then use "MatrixForm" to display a matrix, not "TableForm"

With this you get:

```
n = 3;
u = ConstantArray[1, n];
B = Array[Subscript[b, ##] &, n];
A = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {n, n}];
x = A . u;
A0 = {{1.964888535199277, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.157613081677548, 
    0.485375648722841, 0.0}, {0.970592781760616, 3.800280468888800, 
    2.915735525189067}};
B0 = {0.792207329559554, 2.959492426392903, 0.485375638722841};
eqs = {Transpose[B] . u - 1, Transpose[B] . x - 1/2, 
   Transpose[B] . x^2 - 1/3, Transpose[B] . A . x - 1/6};
LT = {A[[1, 2]] == 0, A[[1, 3]] == 0, A[[2, 3]] == 0};
costFunc = Total[eqs^2];
vars = Join[Transpose@{Flatten[A], Flatten[A0]}, Transpose@{B, B0}];
Results = FindMinimum[{costFunc, LT}, vars]
```

[image]

```
A = A /. Results[[2]][[1 ;; n^2]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
B = B /. Results[[2]][[n^2 + 1 ;;]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to display them as { {....},{....},{..}} rather than the big parentheses?

Comment: Yes, simply eliminate "// MatrixForm". This is the default display form.